# Is there a way to read required AND optional columns with usecols in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is in the context of reading `.csv` files. I want to have a set of "required" columns that pandas will read and parse and a set of "optional" columns that pandas will extract if it is in the `.csv` file or else it won't extract it (I am looping through many different `.csv` files and only want to get the ones that meet these criteria).

Let's say I have data as below:

|  | required_col1 | required_col2 | optional_col1 | optional_col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | a | d |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | b | e |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | c | f |

I would like pandas to require a dataset to have `required_col1`, `required_col2`, and if `optional_col1` is in the dataset, read it, and if it is not, do not raise an error and just move on; the same should be the same for `optional_col2`. However, if the required columns are not in the dataset, I want pandas to raise an error.

I have attempted to use a `lambda` function as such:

```py
columnsList = ['required_col1', 'required_col2', 'optional_col1', 'optional_col2']
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=lambda x: x in columnsList)
```

But, this doesn't work, since it treats *all* list values as optional – so if a dataset has 'optional_col1' and 'required_col2' it will still run through without raising an error (even though 'required_col1' is not in the data).

I've even tried this:

```py
optionalList = ['optional_col1', 'optional_col2']
columnsList = ['required_col1', 'required_col2', lambda x: x in optionalList]
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=columnsList)
```

But, I don't even know if this makes sense on a Python level because I'm unsure if the lambda function will even be accessed when running this through (it wasn't when I tried).

Is there any way that I could get pandas to extract optional columns if there, but also have a set of columns that it *always* should extract from a dataset? Thank you – I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Would putting some `try` and `except` code in help? [Try/Except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Comment: I'm currently using `try` and `except` to see if the dataset has those columns, but I still can't get past the barrier of these optional/required columns -- right now, I can only test if a dataset has the required columns (just straight up putting in a list in `usecols`) OR if it has at least one of the columns (using lambda), but no way of merging these two thoughts

Comment: Hi, I don't get it. Why don't you read the csv, check if required columns are present (else raise error), and then drop all columns that are neither required nor optional?

Comment: I'm running a for loop analyzing over 150 datasets of large sizes, so having `usecols` prevents memory shortage (from what I can tell from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). I thought this would be a better way to go, but I've since figured out a solution to my problem (will answer in a bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still unsure if this *specific question* has an answer within the realms of the pandas API, but I've figured out a way to solve the problem. I've mentioned in the comments that I am trying to run a for loop reading in different datasets running this condition for `usecols`.

As [@Michael S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4458369/michael-s) suggested, `try` and `except` is the way to go here.

First, run through the dataset with the *required* columns, and then append the dataset name to a list.

```py
# list of required columns
requiredList = ['required_col1', 'required_col2']
finalDatasets = []
for i, dataName in enumerate(database)):
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(dataName, usecols=requiredList)
    except:
        continue
    else:
        finalDatasets.append(dataName)
```

Since this new list has gotten rid of the datasets that **do not have the required columns**, you can now run the `lambda` function to parse through optional columns:

```py
columnsList = ['required_col1', 'required_col2', 'optional_col1', 'optional_col2']
for i, dataName in enumerate(finalDatasets):
    # read in data
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(dataName, usecols=lambda x: x in columnsList)
    except:
        continue
    else:
        {insert analysis}
```

This way, you are able to parse through the datasets that **have** the required columns, but you are unsure if they have optional columns (this is where `lambda` comes in handy).

Answer (score 0):

A late answer to this question, but I had this same question and the `lambda` was the way to go. Instead of `try...except`, you could just use the `lambda` from the start and raise an `Exception` if not all the required columns are found, e.g.

```py
import io
import numpy as np

csv_io = io.StringIO("required_col1,required_col2,optional_col1,other_col1\n1,2,3,4")
required_cols = ['required_col1', 'required_col2']
optional_cols = ['optional_col1', 'optional_col2']
data = pd.read_csv(csv_io, usecols=lambda x: x in required_cols + optional_cols)
assert np.isin(required_cols, data.columns).all()
```